# `execute_non_query': Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (DataObjects::SyntaxError)

Tags: sinatra, datamapper, relationships

```
class User

    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,              Serial
    property :name,            String
    property :email,           String

    has n, :records

end


class Project
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,          Serial
    property :name,        String

    has n, :records ?????

end
#
class Record

   # SPEND_REGEX = /^[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}$/

    include DataMapper::Resource


    property :id,                Serial
    property :reporting_type,    String
    property :spend_time,        String

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project ????


end

  DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

With ??? I marked relation that throws an error "`execute_non_query': Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (DataObjects::SyntaxError)
"
How to define 2 has many relationships to one model in datamapper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, your `belongs_to` relationships are required.  I assume you already have `Record` entries in your database.  The `auto_upgrade` is trying to add the new field for the association, and by default it marks that column as `NOT NULL`.  However, for all the existing records, that value *will* be NULL.

To get around this, do one of the following:

- Do an `auto_migrate` instead of `auto_upgrade`.  This will blow away your data, but
  will allow you to add the relationship columns without it choking on
  NULL values.
- Make the associations optional with `:required => false`.  This will allow NULLs in the database.  Next, go in and set those fields to the appropriate values.  Lastly, modify the database table column to be `NOT NULL`.

Comment: This was awesome! Thank you! I was having trouble getting datamapper to add my relationships and found this.